# Jenkins Pipeline stash saves all files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use the following in my pipeline script:

```
stash include: "**/*.log", name: "log_stage1"
```

However, instead of storing the log files it stores everything, and that is 9.2GB of data.

What am I doing wrong?

PS. Thumbs up to Jenkins for being able to handle the data but it just takes about 20 minutes for it to be stashed

Comment: weird, works for me

Comment: It's on a windows slave, could that be an issue?

Comment: At least a difference to mine. But I would expect Jenkins to handle the Ant pattern well on all platforms. Maybe search for bug reports.

Comment: I am indeed searching the bug reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem after many hours. It was a simple typo that was not picked up by the pipeline interpreter, include should be includes, see below:

```
stash includes: "**/*.log", name: "log_stage1"
```